# What requires SessionState in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

In order to help speed up my page load times I am removing SessionState from as many pages as possible. I have a lot of pages viewed that don't require any session tracking.

I know that storing something in the session e.g.

```
Session.Add("name", value);
```

uses the session state, but does anything else or is that it?

I'm using plain old ASP.NET not MVC.

Comment: You can add to session as `Session["name"] = value;`. Does it help?

Comment: Are you sure store something in the `Session` uses the `session state`? I think not, though I'm an mvc Programmer...

Comment: @Kaf - Think you misunderstood my question.

Comment: Ye I wasn't sure what you were after at first. By reading some comments I think you asking `if session being used by the page itself` ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the following link to improve performance and understand session state

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163730.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the link. Can't believe I didn't stumble across it. Very interesting to note that a connection is still made in out-of-box session providers even if session state is disabled for that page. I have some more coding to do, to disable that :)

Answer (score 1):

asp.net controls use viestate or controlstate

if you don't use explicitly session nothing will use session

Answer (score 0):

Removing Session will not speed your page load times a single bit. Session is just a hashtable on the server. In fact clever use of session can improve load times if you use it as a cache mechanism. Maybe you are talking about ViewState or ControlState?

Comment: i don't completely agree with that: sessionstate is deserialized/serialized every time a request is made and this take times

Comment: Sessionstate does increase page load times. I use AppFabric which makes it even more noticable than InProc. Profiling confirms this.

With each page load, it must get the session state from the session provider.

Comment: @giammin this is only true if you are NOT using InProc session.

Comment: @Adam session creates problem with scalability but on a single machine it will not affect performance. If you disagree I will be interested in seeing links that support your statement about session state in non-distributed environment.

Comment: @Stilgar - InProc I agree is v.fast to unnoticable but you have to realize that even a read of SessionState InProc takes up processing time and resources, you don't need a profiler to tell you that. Now add thousands of pageviews per minute and it starts to add up. Every line of code affects performance, it is just to different degrees.

Comment: @Adam sure, every line of code is takes some CPU time but any other way of getting the data (database call for example) is likely to require more processing time than what is essentially an in-memory dictionary. The InProc session does not serialize and deserialize the data as far as I know.

Comment: @Stilgar this is true ALSO if you are using inproc http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC55663.gif that's why object in session must be serializable.

Comment: @giammin that's quite interesting. Can you link the article where this image is from?

Still Session State would be faster than any other means to get the same data because all other ways will also include serialization.

Comment: The article states: "When you use the in-process mode, objects are stored in the session state as live instances of respective classes. No real serialization and deserialization ever takes place, meaning that you can actually store in Session whatever objects you have created (including nonserializable objects and COM objects) and access them with no significant overhead. The situation is different if you opt for an out-of-process state provider." This of course means that the diagram is wrong. BTW it would be easy to test. Add an object in the session, retriee it and compare the references.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

There are there different session states in ASP.NET
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586(v=VS.80).aspx

**In-Process Mode**
The defaul one is `<sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="10" />`, the session will be clear after rebuild the project

**State Server Mode**
we can use this, but remember to turn the services - ASP.NET State Service

```
<sessionState mode="StateServer"
  stateConnectionString="tcpip=localhost:42424"
  sqlConnectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS; User ID=sa;Password=12345678; Integrated Security=SSPI"
  cookieless="false"
  timeout="2"
/>
```

**SQL Server Mode** we can use this after create a DB ASPSate by command, pls check this site for details - http://www.brianstevenson.com/blog/aspstate-concurrently-running-for-net-1011-and-net-20

```
<sessionState mode="SQLServer"
  stateConnectionString="tcpip=localhost:63586"
  sqlConnectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS; User ID=sa;Password=12345678; Integrated Security=SSPI"
  cookieless="false"
  timeout="2"
/>
```

The session in State Server Mode & SQL Server Mode will not be cleared after rebuild the project, it's good for development